# Создать регулярное выражение

Tags: python, re

string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 34"

необходимо, чтобы регулярное выражение искало цифры от 1 до 7, указанные через запятую. В данном случае stdout должен быть такой ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

я пытался искать вот так, но не знаю как учесть запятую:

```
s = re.findall('[1-7]{1}', string)
```

Comment: цифры или числа?

Comment: Необходимы были цифры, т.е. они должны были состоять исключительного из одного символа. Всё что больше должно было отметаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 5"
s = re.findall('(^|[^0-9])([1-7])(\,|$)', string)
s = [x[1] for x in s]
print(s)
```

Вывод в консоль:

> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается из всех только твой сработал)

Answer (score 2):

Если просто найти цифры:

```
re.findall(r'\b[1-7]\b', string)
```

Если запятые принципиально, то:

```
re.findall(r'\b[1-7]\b(?=\s*(?:,|$))', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

вариантов много, вот еще один:

```
string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 34,"
s = re.findall(r'\b([1-7]),',string)
print(s)  # ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```